# Code won't stop executing

Tags: assembly, lc3

Hi I had this code that won't stop executing an I have no idea why. Any Suggestions?

```
LEA R1, SOURCE
 LEA R2, DEST
LOOP: LDR R0, R1, #0
 STR R2, R0, #0
 BRz DONE
 ADD R1, R1, #1
 ADD R2, R2, #1
 BRnzp LOOP
DONE: LEA R0, DEST
 TRAP x22 ; PUTS
 TRAP x25 ; HALT
SOURCE .STRINGZ "\"My sources say no\""
DEST .BLKW #20
```

Comment: `LDR` is loading words, you want bytes. Try with `LDB`/`STB` instead. You have the operands wrong for the store too. Also, you have a debugger/simulator so **use it** to find why the code is broken.

Comment: LDB/STB is LC3-b specific.

Comment: And yeah adding onto my last message in LC3 stringz will fill each word with the characters so its not a problem, but like I said LDB/STB is LC3-b specific which is a slightly different ISA from vanilla LC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I would strongly suggest using an lc3 simulator. Preferably one that allows you to set breakpoints and step through instructions.

Your issue is that you aren't writing the characters to DEST.

```
LDR R0, R1, #0
STR R2, R0, #0
```

You load the character into R0, but you then treat the value in R0 as an address and store whatever is in R2 at that address, this will more than likely overwrite a value in the trap vector table which isn't good (the simulator I work with will warn for stuff like this).

I suppose since you didn't write any characters at DEST as soon as you use PUTS it keeps repeatedly printing out characters until you happen to find a NUL character which probably isn't happening in your simulator.

The fix is to switch R2 and R0 `STR R0, R2, 0`